# how to get a reference number (form of a link) to auto fill part of a form in another html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, onclicklistener

using local storage and `onclick` with javascript

I have a html file with 2 job descriptions :

html file 1

```
<li><Job Reference Number: wru01</li>
<li><Job Reference Number: wru01</li>
```

I need to create a link (using javascript)  that when each job description is clicked it auto fills out the form where the job description should be entered (this form is on another html page)

html file 2:

```
<legend>Job Application Information: </legend>
<label> Job Reference Number: </label>
<input id="refnumber" type="text" name="refnumber" required="required" />
```

so basically i need it that, when, and depending on which job number is clicked wru01 or wru02, it auto fills the job reference number in the form on the next page using local storage.

I have already tried this

js file 1

```
function onclick1() {

  var anchor = document.getElementById('link');

  anchor.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const jobCode = event.target.getAttribute('data-job');

    localStorage.setItem('job-code', jobCode);

    //need redirect user to apply page
    //console.log(event.target)
    window.location = event.target.getAttribute('href');

  })
}


function onclick2() {


  var anchor = document.getElementById('link2');


  anchor.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const jobCode = event.target.getAttribute('data-job');

    localStorage.setItem('job-code', jobCode);

    //need redirect user to apply page
    //console.log(event.target)
    window.location = event.target.getAttribute('href');

  })
}

function init() {

  document.getElementById("link").onclick = function() {
    onclick1()
  };
  document.getElementById("link2").onclick = function() {
    onclick2()
  }
  window.onload = init;
}
```

js file 2

```
function LoadJobCode() {
  var code = localStorage.getItem('job-code');

  if (code) {
    var input = document.getElementById('refnumber');
    // disable text being entered
    input.value = code;
    input.disabled = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me,that's not a good idea to do it.I think you can use `setTimeout` to solve the problem.that's my code:

```
function onclick1() {
     var anchor = document.getElementById('link');
     anchor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const jobCode = event.target.getAttribute('data-job');
            console.log(jobCode)
            localStorage.setItem('job-code', jobCode);
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = event.target.getAttribute('href');
            },1000)

     })
 }
```

why did I do that?That's order to make sure to save the data(`data-job`) before entering another html page.Likewise,you can use `async/await`,such as below:

```
function onclick1() {
        var anchor = document.getElementById('link');
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const jobCode = event.target.getAttribute('data-job');
            console.log(jobCode)
            localStorage.setItem('job-code', jobCode);
            async function locate() {
                await new Promise(() => {
                    window.location.href = event.target.getAttribute('href');
                })
            }
            locate();
        })
    }
```